# Php фильтр HTML кода

Tags: php, json

Я получаю такую страницу:

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198124466143",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Scream Cream",
            "lastlogoff": 1442853015,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124466143/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "Илья Донец",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791429521408",
            "timecreated": 1390843803,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "UA",
            "locstatecode": "12"
        }
    ]

}
}
```

Как вывести текст между `"avatarmedium": "` и `"`?
Иными словами, как вывести только ссылку на картинку? Для кода выше должно получиться:

> https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9.jpg

Comment: `$arr = json_decode($string); $arr['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) вам в помощь.

```
$r = json_decode($output);
var_dump($r->response->players[0]->avatar);
```

Фигурные скобки - stdclass, квадратные - массив.
Если больше нравится только через массивы:

```
$r = json_decode($output, true);
var_dump($r['response']['players'][0]['avatar']);
```

Comment: Вывод: `string(116) "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f4/f4e7432889c3773c1f585f0f5ccf488fec760a5b.jpg"`

Comment: @Sauron так вам же эту ссылку и нужно получить, разве нет?

Comment: Вывод должен быть `https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f4/f4e7432‌​889c3773c1f585f0f5ccf488fec760a5b.jpg` проста я не хочу нагрузку делать через explode

Comment: @Sauron var_dump() показывает тип переменной. Тогда вместо `var_dump` нужно просто `echo` сделать: `echo $r['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];`

Comment: А ясно спс.Еще маленький вопрос какой быстрее работает?: `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ссылкана сайт');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); ` или же `file_get_contents`

Comment: Та одинаково будет. Если больше ничего не нужно со страницы (заголовки, например), то можете file_get_contents делать.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос решен:

```
 $String = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=D809927A12701C14A968491B9518BBB6&steamids='.$prof[steam_id].'");
$mail = explode('               ', $String);
$mail = explode('"', $mail[8]);
$mail = $mail[3];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

/**
 * Получить данные о игроке по ключу
 * @param type $char
 * @param type $player_data
 * @return type
 */
function get_player_char($char, $player_data) {
    if (isset($player_data->$char)) {
        return $player_data->$char;
    }
    return false;
}

$json = '{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198124466143",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Scream Cream",
            "lastlogoff": 1442853015,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198124466143/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9b/9b888d9db734bc32cf30dc82d391ea69bf066cc9_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "Илья Донец",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791429521408",
            "timecreated": 1390843803,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "UA",
            "locstatecode": "12"
        }
    ]

}
}';

$response_data = json_decode($json);

$avatar = get_player_char("avatar", $response_data->response->players[0]);
```

Comment: Отдельная функция для получения поля объекта - это уже перебор.